# Is there a good notation for stacking matrices into a tensor?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, tensors, machine-learning

Let $v_1, v_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be two vectors,

then a matrix with these vectors as columns is usually denoted as $M = [v_1|v_2]$

---

Now suppose I have matrices $M_1, M_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$

I want to represent the 3D tensor which is by stacking these matrices

[image]

Is $T = [M_1 | M_2]$ a good way of representation this tensor? Or is there some other way of representing this "embedding"?

Comment: What exactly you mean by "representing"? Like in term of notation? Writing $[M1, M2]$ seems good enough for me.

Comment: You mean the Kronecker product of matrices.

Comment: @Wuestenfux No, they mean a three-dimensional table containing all the entries of the two matrices. Not a larger 2-dimensional table containing all the pairwise products of the entries.